# Azure functions with service bus as output binding not working

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I am trying to send a message to a service bus though an output binding in azure functions in Javascript.

I am testing locally using the azure function cli and starting the host as `func host start` as I always used.

My setup is something like this:

`function.json`

```
{
  "disabled": false,

  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "put"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "serviceBus",
      "name" : "locationQueue",
      "queueName": "location_queue",
      "direction": "out",
      "accessRights": "Manage",
      "connection": "service-bus_CONNECTION"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

And the function *after some promises* ends like this:

```
.then( () => {
        var message = {
            userID : userID,
            lat: userCurrentLocation.lat,
            long: userCurrentLocation.long,
            time: new Date()
        };
        context.bindings.locationQueue = [JSON.stringify(message)];
        context.res = {
            status: 200,
            body: ''
        }
        context.done();
    })
    .catch( (err) => {
        console.error("Error while trying to update userID %s location.", userID, err)
        context.res = {
            status: 500,
            body: ''
        }
        context.done();
    })
```

The request ends succesfully with a 200 status code.

The connection string was generated by azure portal and seems to be connecting as the dashboard presents new connections when I am testing. I even tried to put a wrong connection string but the function host did not complain at all!

But the queue is not created and no message is sent. I tried to create the queue myself and the message was not sent either.

What is happening? What I did wrong? More, if I did something wrong, shouldn't I receive an error message even in logs? I mean, how can I trust everything is right if a message is not send and no error is logged anywere?

Comment: Is this Functions v1 or Functions v2?

Comment: It is Functions V1, it is for a production environment so we are not getting preview

Comment: Are you sure the function hits the last promise at all?

Comment: Yes, I debugged it and it hits the last .then